# Finding the length of a line drawn from the right angle to the hypotenuse.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm supposed to find the length of the line drawn from a point on the hypotenuse of a right triangle to the right angle.  Obviously I'm able to find line AB but that doesn't help me find AD as far as I can tell.

I thought about the Alternate interior angles rules but they apply to parallel lines.

A little difficult to google search for the answer due to the nature of the question.

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUyp3.jpg)

Comment: You should mention that $AD \perp BC$ in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that the area of triangle $ABC$ is $\frac 12\times AB\times AC$, but it is also $\frac 12\times AD\times BC$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the right angle and we drop a perpendicular $AD$ to $BC$, then $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle ABC$; thus

$\dfrac{AD}{AB} = \dfrac{AC}{BC} \tag 1$

or

$AD = \dfrac{(AB)(AC)}{BC}. \tag 2$